# Appending files name along with path in a variable in batch file reading from folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to read files name along with path and store it in single variable differentiate each path by comma. below is my try but every time if i run it is showing single file name even though it is running in for loop.

code:

```
@echo off
for %%F  in ("C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\*.*") do (
set file=%%F
echo done copying files: %file%
)
```

Folder contains files: 
C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\

```
Pwm_1.txt
Pwm_2.txt
Pwm_3.txt
Pwm_4.txt
Pwm_5.txt
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop>File_Read.bat
done copying files: C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_5.txt
done copying files: C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_5.txt
done copying files: C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_5.txt
done copying files: C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_5.txt
done copying files: C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_5.txt
```

Expected output:

variable "file" should contain:
"C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_1.txt,C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_2.txt,C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_3.txt,C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_4.txt,C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\Pwm_5.txt"

Comment: Compo showed one way how to append to a variable. That your output shows only one file is because of missing [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Yes, after providing SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion it is working fine. thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\*") Do If Not Defined file (
    Set "file=%%A") Else Call Set "file=%%file%%,%%A"
Echo %file%
Timeout -1
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. the code is working fine but it is working fine at the first execution. second time if we run the batch file, previous content of "file" variable is appended with same and content of "file" variable is multiplied with same content every time running the batch. is there any command to de-initialize the "file" variable ?.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, does adding `"Set file="` before the `For` loop do what you want?

Comment: @ compo, I am a beginner in batch scripting. Lets put it in this way, when the scope of the variable "file" will end or when the content of the variable will be destroyed ?

Comment: The variable is not retained beyond the batch file or cmd instance. If you wish to keep it beyond that take a look at `SetX /?`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i just added two line in your code now it is working fine. @Echo Off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=
For %%A In ("C:\Users\a5100893\Desktop\source_files\*") Do If Not Defined file (
    Set "file=%%A") Else Call Set "file=%%file%%,%%A"
Echo %file%

Comment: Remove the `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` or change it to `SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion` Also please ensure that you change `set file=` to `Set "file="`. Please also mark this as answered.

Comment: Ya. SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion and Set "file=" used. Thanks for your advice.